# Prevent direct module import in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular5

I have a feature module that declares my components and also has a static function that configures feature routing.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: FEATURE_COMPONENTS,
  entryComponents: FEATURE_COMPONENTS,
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule {
  public static setParentState(stateName: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    ...
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      providers: [
        ...UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: ... }).providers
        // my providers
        {
          provide: FEATURE_PROVIDER_TOKEN,
          useValue: ...
          multi: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

My module on its own isn't enough to actually use the features, it also needs routing configuration which is done correctly through upper static function.

I would like to prevent this scenario:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    // invalid import - I want to prevent this one
    FeatureModule
    // valid import
    FeatureModule.setParentState(...)
  ]
})
export class SomeAppModule {}
```

**How can I throw some error when user tries to import my feature module directly as per above code?** Correct import would be through calling the static function and not directly...

One of the possible things I might be able to use is the extra provider I'm adding my static function. But how? Via module constructor and its injections? Maybe via some custom decorator?

I was thinking of doing it this way somehow, but would also like to provide some custom error message with information how to correctly import the module:

```
@NgModule({ ... })
export class FeatureModule {
  public static setParentState(stateName: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    // FEATURE_PROVIDER_TOKEN defined here (see above)
    ...
  }

  constructor(
    @Import(FEATURE_PROVIDER_TOKEN) tokenTest: any
  } {
    // this will throw an error when provider isn't defined, but won't allow me to set specific error message
  }
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: User that voted to close: I updated my question with some additional code, to make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### One possible and working solution

This is what I've implemented and it seems to satisfy the requirements:

1. It doesn't allow importing a module directly
2. It throws and error which describes correct usage

This is how it's implemented:

```
const PREVENT_DIRECT_IMPORT: InjectionToken<boolean> = new InjectionToken('FeatureModule:PREVENT_DIRECT_IMPORT');

@NgModule({
  declarations: FEATURE_COMPONENTS,
  entryComponents: FEATURE_COMPONENTS,
  imports: [ ... ],
  exports: [ ... ]
  providers: [{
    // erroneous provider when module is directly imported
    provide: PREVENT_DIRECT_IMPORT,
    useFactory: () => { throw new Error('Correct usage info'); },
    multi: false
  }]
})
export class FeatureModule {
  public static setParentState(stateName: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    ...
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      providers: [
        ...UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: ... }).providers
        // my providers
        {
          provide: FEATURE_PROVIDER_TOKEN,
          useValue: ...
          multi: false
        }, {
          // this is the same provider when module is correctly imported
          provide: PREVENT_DIRECT_IMPORT,
          useValue: true,
          multi: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  constructor(
    @Import(PREVENT_DIRECT_IMPORT) prevent: boolean
  ) {
    // direct import will throw error when DI tries to get the injected provider
  }
}
```

Comment: ...with me having discovered this answer a few years later, I feel I should share what I know now. :) here in 2022 we do have slightly simpler options, especially for "simpler" requirements, have a look here: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/guarding-your-angular-modules#a-second-solution-but-different